# How to update Cached Page from an Asyn Task After Navigating to another Page?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am Navigating from a Page to another page when a background downloading work is going on.
In the **Page 1**, I'm updating a progress bar based on the progress received.
I've cached **Page1** before Navigating to **Page 2**.

But when We Navigate back to **Page1**, the View is not updated even if we have updated Model and Notified it using MVVM method. But W've verified that the progress is completed and the file is downloaded.

We are using the below code to cache Page.

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

I am wondering why the View is not updated, even if we have tried to update it. If we are not Navigating to another page, the progress is updated. So We are sure that it will work on normal case except on caching.

Please help on this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I come to a workaround solution. I found that while Navigating back, only PageLoad is invoked again. So I kept all Tasks to be loaded at PageLoad in the Page constructor after the

this.InitializeComponent();

And it turned out to be a workaround for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

clearing cache should help you

override the following in your caller page

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("/target"))
    {
        Frame parentFrame = (Frame) Parent;
        var cacheSize = parentFrame.CacheSize;
        parentFrame.CacheSize = 0;
        parentFrame.CacheSize = cacheSize;
    }
    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
}
```

replace `/target` with your intended url or replace the condition with your own logic eg. after you update your view model or both

idea behind is to see when we are `navigating` to the `cached target` then we set the `cache size` of the frame to `0` which will effectively `clear the cache` and then `restore back` the original limit to start caching again.

**Note** this method is effective for `NavigationCacheMode.Enabled` only it may not work for `NavigationCacheMode.Required` as it is more difficult to clear.

Comment: I've one doubt. I have kept NavigationCacheMode as Enabled to achieve one requirement. In the Page 1, I am downloading a File and notifying Progress of it, So clearing cache will abrupt the file downloading? And if not, will the progressbar be updated till the download progress is completed?

Comment: I hope it should not interrupt the file download unless being downloaded withing the page code and also it depends on the method of download. So far I guess you are using the pages to display information, not performing such business logic. Just give it a try and see if this can solve your particular case. If not then is it possible for you to post a working sample for your case, so I can propose a solution based on your needs.

Comment: It tried this but it is affecting the downloading progress. When I Navigated back to the Page 1, then progress is closed even though the download is going on in background.

Comment: I am sure we can handle that.  Is it possible for you to create a working sample which can reproduce the same issue? May I have a look and see how we can solve the issue.